# Mongoose code hangs at new Types.ObjectId(userid)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I have the following Mongoose code in my app

```
const generatedId = new Types.ObjectId(userid)
UserModel.findById( new Types.ObjectId(generatedId)).exec((result) => {...})
```

This works find as long as `userid` is an actual id used in my MongoDB database.

However, what I've discovered, is that if `userid` received something like `blabla` which is not a valid `_id`, this code just hangs to infinity. It never gets past `generatedId`.

Why does this happen and how can it be prevented?